# PHP FFmpeg not working in windowxp and on live website same code working in ubuntu

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, ffmpeg

Here is my script i want to work in all case :
Its working in only ubuntu but not in all case like windowsxp
Please suggest me...

```
    // where ffmpeg is located, such as /usr/sbin/ffmpeg
    $ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg';

    // the input video file
    $video  = "upload/uploads/movies/animations/dhoom-2.mp4";

    // where you'll save the image
    $image  = "upload/uploads/movies/animations/images/dhoom-2.jpg";

    // default time to get the image
    $second = 1;

    // get the duration and a random place within that
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1";
    if (preg_match('/Duration: ((\d+):(\d+):(\d+))/s', `$cmd`, $time)) 
    {
        $total = ($time[2] * 3600) + ($time[3] * 60) + $time[4];
        $second = rand(1, ($total - 1));
    }

    // get the screenshot
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 04 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";
    $return = `$cmd`;

        echo "<script>alert('done!');</script>";
    ?>
    <img src="upload/uploads/movies/animations/images/dhoom-2.jpg" alt=";-)" class="wp-smiley"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the "exec" / "shell_exec" for execution like below , try the same.

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 04 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";
return exec($cmd);
```

Comment: You can also refer the link : How to Install FFmpeg on Windows http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows

Comment: return exec($cmd); its fine and also working in ubuntu 
but not in windows

Comment: Please check your windows ffmpeg path and call with same path or set the ffmpeg path

Comment: i use $ffmpeg="ffmpeg"; variable its working without any ffmpeg installation in ubuntu but its not working in windows.

Comment: If you did not install ffmpeg then please install from this link (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), if you are comparing with ubuntu , might be pre-installed ffmpeg library and in your script clearly mentioned the ffmpeg pathh"// where ffmpeg is located, such as /usr/sbin/ffmpeg", so please install ffmpeg first on windows